# Need explanation of XPath syntax

Tags: xml, xpath, msxml

Can anyone explain the XPath syntax written below:

```
xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//*/Expression[.!='']")
```

Basically, I need clarification of the argument path of the above syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the `<Expression>` elements which:

1. are not root elements
2. and have non-empty value

`//*/` - this means any but root

`Expression` - element name

`[.!='']` - this means current node value is not empty, i.e. current node `.` is not `!=` empty `''`

Answer (score 2):

`//*`   selects *all* elements.

`//*/Expression` selects all `Expression` *child* elements.

`//*/Expression[.!='']` selects all `Expression` child elements with *non-empty **[string-values](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value)***.

[XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes):

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the
>   string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in
>   document order.

**Note**: This is *not* the same as being *[empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-content)*.  Empty elements have no children at all.

**Consider an example:**

```
<Expression id="e1"> 
  <Expression id="e2"/>  
  <Expression id="e3"><c/></Expression> 
  <Expression id="e4"> 
    <b/> 
  </Expression>  
  <Expression id="e5"> 
    <a>text1</a> 
  </Expression>  
  <Expression id="e6">test2<c/></Expression> 
</Expression>
```

`Expression` `e1` **would not be selected** because as the root element it is not a *child* of any other element.

`Expression` `e2` **would not be selected** because its string-value is ''.

`Expression` `e3` **would not be selected** because its string-value is '', even though `e3` is not itself empty.

`Expression` elements `e4`, `e5`, and `e6` **would be selected** because they all have non-empty string-values.

Comment: I would suggest this as a better answer since it goes into details about what `not empty` means.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*
```

Select any element anywhere in the XML document

```
/Expression[.!='']
```

Then from that element, get all *direct child* `<Expression>` elements having non-empty value.